# jQuery .append option to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following simple HTML code with 2 SELECT forms with identical options values:

```html
<select id="first">
    <option value="none">None</option>
  <optgroup label="Main">
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="tre">Honda</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="second">
  <optgroup label="Main">
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="tre">Honda</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="third">
  <optgroup label="Main">
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Other">
    <option value="tre">Honda</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

I am writing a jQuery script that should do following: if in the #first select I choose any value except "none", f.e. Toyota, it will automatically disappear from the #second select:

```html
<select id="second">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
</select>
```

further, if I choose Nissan in the #second select(assuming #first still have Toyota selected), it should automatically disappear from the #first select:

```html
<select id="first">
    <option selected="selected" value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
```

At the end, when I reset selector to "None" in any select form, it should recreate that option in another select on the same position.

I know how to remove and append removed  to the end of options list, the question is how to append removed option to the position that it was before?

I am using following jscript for remove append options:

```js
$(document).on('change','#first',   function() {
    fsel = $(this).attr('id');
    fval = $(this).val();
    ftext = $(this).children('option:selected').text();

    if (fval === "none" ) {
            $("#second").append('<option value="'+ firstval +'">'+firsttext+'</option>');
          }
    else if ( typeof firstval != 'undefined' && fval != firstval) {
            $("#second").append('<option value="'+ firstval +'">'+firsttext+'</option>');
            $("#second option[value="+fval+"]").remove();
            firstval = fval;
            firsttext = ftext;
    }
    else {
            firstval = fval;
            firsttext = ftext;
            $("#second option[value="+fval+"]").remove();
          }
});

$(document).on('change','#second',   function() {
    ssel = $(this).attr('id');
    sval = $(this).val();
    stext = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
    if (sval === "none" ) {
            $("#second").append('<option value="'+ secondval +'">'+secondtext+'</option>');
     }
    else if ( typeof secondval != 'undefined' && sval != secondval) {
            $("#second").append('<option value="'+ secondval +'">'+secondtext+'</option>');
            $("#second option[value="+sval+"]").remove();
            secondval = sval;
            secondtext = stext;
    }
    else {
            secondval = sval;
            secondtext = stext;
            $("#second option[value="+sval+"]").remove();
         }
});
```

PS. Please don't offer .hide/.show - it doesn't work in some browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to remember all the options, I re-write the code, hope it can be helpful.

```
    var sel1 = $('#first'), sel2 = $('#second');

//get the options value/text of some selection

/**
 * get the options value/text map of some select element
 * 
 * @param sel
 *            a select element
 * 
 * 
 * @return {val1:txt1, val2:txt2....}
 */
function getSelOptions(sel) {

    var opts = {}, tmp;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++) {
        tmp = sel.options[i];
        opts[tmp.value] = tmp.text;
    }

    return opts;
}

/**
 * Reset the select element's options
 * 
 * @param sel
 *            the select element
 * @param newOptions
 *            the new options map
 * @param except
 *            the option value which will be excluded
 */
function setOptionsExcept(sel, newOptions, except) {

    //remember the current select value
    var curSel = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

    //clear the select options
    sel.options.length = 0;

    for ( var k in newOptions) {

        //this one should be excludeed
        if (k != "none" && k == except)
            continue;

        //add to the option list
        sel.options.add(new Option(newOptions[k], k, false, k == curSel));
    }

}

//remember the options map
var opts1 = getSelOptions(sel1.get(0)), opts2 = getSelOptions(sel2.get(0));

sel1.change(function() {

    //sel1 value
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "none") {
        //as sel1 is none, reset sel1
        setOptionsExcept(this, opts1);
    }

    //reset sel2, but no sel1 value
    setOptionsExcept(sel2.get(0), opts2, val);
});

sel2.change(function() {

    //sel2 value
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "none") {
        //as sels is none, reset sel2
        setOptionsExcept(this, opts2);
    }

    //reset sel1, but no sel2 value
    setOptionsExcept(sel1.get(0), opts1, val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/PGqv7/3/

Comment: thanks so far, we are closer to the solution, but in your code I cannot choose toyota and nissan in different selects, it reset another to -> None, try yourself :(

Comment: Just update. now it will remember the selected value when re-set options.

Comment: year it works now, thanks a lot, I am gonna test it with more selects.

Comment: Andrew, sorry being so late, but could you please add into your code 3rd select ? cause I cannot adjust it myself correctly.

Comment: And what to do if i am using <optgoup> between options ?

Comment: I just add some comments, hope the code can be more easily understood. How will sel1 and sel2 change if sel3 change? optgoup will be a little complicated, getSelOptions should be change to get not only key:value, but group:key:value.

Comment: thanks I will review it,   I corrected code in the original message,please take a look, the logic is the same, if sel3 is selected, then selected option should be excluded from sel1 and sel2, after reseting to none, removed option should be added on the same place in sel1 and sel2

Comment: hm. but last 3 select doesnt work for me...  well, ok I created that from scratch look: http://jsfiddle.net/serg77/6QgLD/1/    However my code is too big, i doubt its optimized, what you say?

Comment: nevermind, i sorted it out, I put everything into function and now it works perfectly. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery post() and some PHP to do that. First seperate your data from your code by putting placeholders in your HTML:

```
<form id="formname" name="formname">
<div id="first_select"></div>
<div id="second_select"></div>
</form>
```

First thing after the document is ready: Initialize the placeholders

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("init_first_select.php", function(response) {
        $("#first_select").html(response);
    });

    $.get("init_second_select.php", function(response) {
        $("#second_select").html(response);
    });
});
```

Inside init_first_select.php you call your database and get the data for the first select-box, arrange it and return the HTML-code, like this:

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
</select>
```

Then use change() and post() to react to the users selection:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
    var data = $("#formname").serialize();
    $.post("update_second_select.php", data, function(response) {
        $("#second_select").html(response);
    });
});
```

Inside the PHP-file you process the data and return HTML-Code for each  which is then inserted at the #second_select placeholder. You can use all the array manipulation functions in PHP to do whatever you need.

The same applies for the second select-box:

```
$('#second').change(function() {
    var data = $("#formname").serialize();
    $.post("update_first_select.php", data, function(response) {
        $("#first_select").html(response);
    });
});
```

Of course you could do all that data processing in one PHP-file. ;-)

Comment: actually, i dont wanna use backend, all work should be done on client side using javascripts/jquery